# How to get AnyTime14 Organizer to run

Tags: windows-7

I have purchased organizer software for windows.  I am running windows 7.  The organizer is AnyTime14 and it has an activation code.  However when I input the code I get a message telling me that the program cannot make contact with the activation server. I have turned off my firewall but that did not help.  I have contacted Herman Street the suppliers but they have not responded

Answer (score 0):

From the [support pages](http://www.individualsoftware.com/activation/):

You may have a program running on your computer that will not allow the software to verify the activation key. Try the following steps to connect to the activation server.

1. Disable any firewall you have running on your computer or wireless router.
2. Ensure you have Internet connection on your computer.

That seems to cover the issues I would think of. Are you on a corporate network? Maybe their firewall is blocking access?

Note that Herman Street are just a supplier, they are not the originators of the software, you need to contact "Individual Software".